# List Comparison Algorithm: How can it be made better?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

*Running on Python 3.3*

I am attempting to create an efficient algorithm to pull all of the similar elements between two lists. **The problem is two fold. First, I can not seem to find any algorithms online. Second, there *should* be a more efficient way.**

By '*similar elements*', I mean two elements that are equal in value (be it `string`, `int`, whatever).

Currently, I am taking a [greedy approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) by:

1. Sorting the lists that are being compared,
2. Comparing each element in the shorter list to each element in the larger list,
3. Since the `largeList` and `smallList` are sorted we can save the last index that was visited,
4. Continue from the previous index (`largeIndex`).

Currently, the run-time seems to be average of `O(nlog(n))`. This can be seen by **running the test cases listed after this block of code**.

Right now, my code looks as such:

```
  def compare(small,large,largeStart,largeEnd):
        for i in range(largeStart, largeEnd):
              if small==large[i]:
                    return [1,i]
              if small<large[i]:
                    if i!=0:
                          return [0,i-1]
                    else:
                          return [0, i]
        return [0,largeStart]

  def determineLongerList(aList, bList):
    if len(aList)>len(bList):
        return (aList, bList)
    elif len(aList)<len(bList):
        return (bList, aList)
    else:
        return (aList, bList)

  def compareElementsInLists(aList, bList):
        import time
        startTime   = time.time()
        holder      = determineLongerList(aList, bList)
        sameItems   = []
        iterations  = 0
        ##########################################
        smallList   = sorted(holder[1])
        smallLength = len(smallList)
        smallIndex  = 0
        largeList   = sorted(holder[0])
        largeLength = len(largeList)
        largeIndex  = 0
        while (smallIndex<smallLength):
              boolean = compare(smallList[smallIndex],largeList,largeIndex,largeLength)
              if boolean[0]==1:
                    #`compare` returns 1 as True
                    sameItems.append(smallList[smallIndex])
                    oldIndex    = largeIndex
                    largeIndex  = boolean[1]
              else:
                    #else no match and possible new index
                    oldIndex    = largeIndex
                    largeIndex  = boolean[1]
              smallIndex+=1
              iterations =largeIndex-oldIndex+iterations+1
        print('RAN {it} OUT OF {mathz} POSSIBLE'.format(it=iterations, mathz=smallLength*largeLength))
  print('RATIO:\t\t'+str(iterations/(smallLength*largeLength))+'\n')
  return sameItems
```

, and here are some test cases:

```
  def testLargest():
        import time
        from random import randint
        print('\n\n******************************************\n')
        start_time  = time.time()
        lis   = []
        for i in range(0,1000000):
              ran   = randint(0,1000000)
              lis.append(ran)
        lis2  = []
        for i in range(0,1000000):
              ran   = randint(0,1000000)
              lis2.append(ran)
        timeTaken   = time.time()-start_time     
        print('CREATING LISTS TOOK:\t\t'+str(timeTaken))
        print('\n******************************************')
        start_time  = time.time()
        c           = compareElementsInLists(lis, lis2)
        timeTaken   = time.time()-start_time     
        print('COMPARING LISTS TOOK:\t\t'+str(timeTaken))
        print('NUMBER OF SAME ITEMS:\t\t'+str(len(c)))
        print('\n******************************************')

  #testLargest()

  '''
  One rendition of testLargest:
        ******************************************

        CREATING LISTS TOOK:        21.009342908859253

        ******************************************
        RAN 999998 OUT OF 1000000000000 POSSIBLE
        RATIO:      9.99998e-07

        COMPARING LISTS TOOK:       13.99990701675415
        NUMBER OF SAME ITEMS:       632328

        ******************************************
  '''

  def testLarge():
        import time
        from random import randint
        print('\n\n******************************************\n')
        start_time  = time.time()
        lis   = []
        for i in range(0,1000000):
              ran   = randint(0,100)
              lis.append(ran)
        lis2  = []
        for i in range(0,1000000):
              ran   = randint(0,100)
              lis2.append(ran)
        timeTaken   = time.time()-start_time     
        print('CREATING LISTS TOOK:\t\t'+str(timeTaken))
        print('\n******************************************')
        start_time  = time.time()
        c           = compareElementsInLists(lis, lis2)
        timeTaken   = time.time()-start_time     
        print('COMPARING LISTS TOOK:\t\t'+str(timeTaken))
        print('NUMBER OF SAME ITEMS:\t\t'+str(len(c)))
        print('\n******************************************')

  testLarge()
```

Comment: See code review rather than stack overflow.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi is that a stack domain?

Comment: Yes, here's the [link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yeah, well, but I'm reluctant to call for a close on this; it asks for improvement on existing code and algorithm.  It doesn't just say "Here's my code, any suggestions?".

Comment: @T.Woody, could you elaborate on what you mean by "similar" in the first lines of your description?

Comment: @Alfe, how does that look?

Comment: Still no explanation when two elements are considered "similar".  Do you mean equal?

Comment: @Alfe, I do. I'll add that as well.

Comment: @Alfe Asking for improvements on existing code can make for very on-topic questions on [codereview.se], as long as it's not "I want to add feature X".  In fact, questions as blanketed as "Here's my code, any suggestions?" aren't really that great on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just searching for all elements which are in both lists, you should use data types meant to handle such tasks.  In this case, `set`s or `bag`s would be appropriate.  These are internally represented by hashing mechanisms which are even more efficient than searching in sorted lists.

(`collections.Counter` represents a suitable `bag`.)

If you do not care for doubled elements, then `set`s would be fine.

```
a = set(listA)
print a.intersection(listB)
```

This will print all elements which are in `listA` and in `listB`.  (Without doubled output for doubled input elements.)

```
import collections

a = collections.Counter(listA)
b = collections.Counter(listB)

print a & b
```

This will print how many elements are how often in both lists.

I didn't make any measuring but I'm pretty sure these solutions are way faster than your self-made attempts.

To convert a counter into a `list` of all represented elements again, you can use `list(c.elements())`.

Comment: Did a quick timeit: `1000 loops, best of 3: 636 µs per loop`

Comment: @Alfe, I am playing around with [collection docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) now, and am having a hard time seeing how I can implement a similar result as I am looking for in a quick fashion.

Comment: Do mean back into a list? `[k for k in counter for _ in range(counter[k])]`

Comment: Thank you @achampion for providing a quick implementation for OP's last question, but I think using the built-in solutions should be preferred (see my last edit):  `list(c.elements())`.

Comment: @Alfe I ran some more test cases and read the python code of collections. `__ior__` seems to be working **MUCH** faster! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Using ipython magic for timeit but it doesn't compare favourably with just a standard `set()` intersection.
Setup:

```
import random
alist = [random.randint(0, 100000) for _ in range(1000)]
blist = [random.randint(0, 100000) for _ in range(1000)]
```

Compare Elements:

```
%%timeit -n 1000
compareElementsInLists(alist, blist)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.9 ms per loop
```

Vs Set Intersection

```
%%timeit -n 1000
set(alist) & set(blist)
1000 loops, best of 3: 104 µs per loop
```

Just to make sure we get the same results:

```
>>> compareElementsInLists(alist, blist)
[8282, 29521, 43042, 47193, 48582, 74173, 96216, 98791]
>>> set(alist) & set(blist)
{8282, 29521, 43042, 47193, 48582, 74173, 96216, 98791}
```

Comment: I'm going to look up `set`. I haven't seen it before. Could you provide some explanation to `set` in the meantime? That is, what is going on here? 0.o

Comment: `set()` is a standard python type it is like list but collapses duplicates and has no guaranteed order. This just uses the intersection of 2 sets... you can always extract these values out of the original list if you need duplicates.

Comment: I substituted the value of `c` in my test cases for `set(lis)&set(lis2)`. Both of these `lists` contain the same randomly generated numbers. Mine ran in 11 seconds while `set` ran in  21 seconds. I am running a few more test cases to see if this is a case of `sort`. Also, it is not keeping repeated items (i.e. `set([4,4,4]) & set([4,4]) == {4}` if my understanding is right?)

Comment: Correct, see `collections.Counter` solution if you care about dupes. I somewhat skeptical that the set solution takes nearly twice as long as a sort solution.

Comment: Yeah, I was just reading the replies, thank you as well for the time :) What are your thoughts on why my `timeit` seems to be on the other side of the spectrum that you provided?